# more that 1mb data in memcahed nodejs

Tags: node.js, memcached

I am using this [memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/memcached) package with nodejs. As default max size of data per key is 1mb i am facing problem when data is more than 1mb for a particular key.

One work around would be in `memcache.conf` setting default max size more than 1 mb using

```
-I 2M
```

and in code setting the `maxValue`

```
var memcached = new Memcached('localhost:11211', {maxValue: 2097152});
```

What would be proper way to stay in 1mb limit? I have read suggestion about splitting data into multiple keys. How can i achieve multiple key splitting with JSON data in [memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/memcached) package.

Comment: not clear about your question. so after these two steps, you still can't set a key with value more than 1Mb or what ?

Comment: I have edited question description to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

Options available :

1/ Make sure you are using compression while storing them in memcached, your nodejs memcached driver would be supporting gzip compression.

2/ Split the data into multiple keys

3/ Increase max object size to more than 1 MB ( but that may increase fragmentation,decrease performance based on your cache usage )

4/ Use redis as cache instead of memcached if your object sizes are usually large. Redis string datatype supports objects upto 512 MB in size, that would be easily available as direct get,set interface in any standard nodejs-redis cache driver